# Has anyone ever propose a theory of infinitesimals, based on this principle?

Tags: integration, infinitesimals

We know that in the theory of distributions $\int_{-1}^1 \delta(x)dx=1$.

Now consider a function $f(x)$ which is equal to $1$ at $x=0$ but otherwise is zero.

Did anyone propose a generalization of integration, under which $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)dx$ is an infinitesimal?

This would allow to compare infinitesimals, multiply them by real numbers, etc...

Comment: Well if you integrate $f$ with respect to the $\delta_0$ measure, you get $1$ .

Answer (score 0):

Well this would have an exact value as $dx$ when $dx$ is considered the small number you break Reimann integrals up into, so I think it should have the same value as the infinitesimal typically denoted $\epsilon$ or $\frac{1}{\omega}$ that is used in non-standard analysis (analysis that makes infinitesimals rigorous).

Comment: Why do you think it would be $dx$? Also, in non-standard analysis $\omega$ is usually infinite, not infinitely small.

Comment: You're right about that $\omega$, It would be dx because you are adding $0dx$ a bunch of times, except at $0$, when it is $1 dx$.